# Preventing JS function from running everytime the DOM content is loaded?

Tags: javascript

I'm having a problem where I want to run the `load_mailbox('inbox')` only when the page is first loaded, but when a form is submitted, I want to load the mailbox with other parameter ('sent'), as the code below illustrates. But what I think is happening, is that, since the `load_mailbox('inbox')` is inside a DOMContentLoaded event listener, it is being run even when the `load_mailbox('sent')` finishes loading, can anyone think of a way to prevent it from doing so, or another solution to this problem?

Code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  // By default, load the inbox
  load_mailbox('inbox');

  document.querySelector('#compose-form').onsubmit = function() {

    //Declaring email variables
    const recipients = document.querySelector('#compose-recipients').value
    const subject = document.querySelector('#compose-subject').value
    const body = document.querySelector('#compose-body').value

    //Making API request
    fetch('/emails', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        recipients: recipients,
        subject: subject,
        body: body
      })
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => {
      console.log(result);
      load_mailbox('sent');
    }); 
  }


});
```

Comment: note you havent prevented the default action of the submit event which is to submit the form and transition to the action url of the form(the same page if it hasnt been set). So the event isnt firing again the whole page has reloaded and the processes has started over

Comment: @PatrickEvans wow, just added a return false; to the callback of the onsubmit listener and it works, I didn't know that forms worked like this

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by @PatrickEvans the problem was that **the form was performing its default action**, which is to reload the url, so preventing it from doing so with a return false; in the end of the submit callback function fixed it!

now the eventlistener and its callback look like this:

```
document.querySelector('#compose-form').onsubmit = function() {

    //Declaring email variables
    const recipients = document.querySelector('#compose-recipients').value
    const subject = document.querySelector('#compose-subject').value
    const body = document.querySelector('#compose-body').value

    //Making API request
    fetch('/emails', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        recipients: recipients,
        subject: subject,
        body: body
      })
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => {
      console.log(result);
      load_mailbox('sent');
    });

    return false;
  }
```